# OpenMP Monte_Carlo simulation achieve target closeness to PI

Tags: c, openmp, montecarlo

I am trying to write a parallel program which takes an error rate(i.e 0.01) and returns a PI value which is closer to PI than the error with montecarlo simulation.
I wrote a simple function however it does not terminate as error rate is always around 11.
I appreciate your comments.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "omp.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>

double drand48(void);

double monte_carlo(double epsilon){
    double x,y, pi_estimate = 0.0;
    double drand48(void);
    double error = 10000.0;
    int n = 0; // total number of points
    int i = 0; // total numbers of points inside circle
    int p = omp_get_num_threads();
    while(error>=epsilon){
        #pragma omp parallel private(x, y) reduction(+:i)//OMP parallel directive
        {
            x = drand48();
            y = drand48();
            if((x*x+y*y)<=1.0){i+=1;}
        }
        n+=p;
        printf("%lf\n", error);
        pi_estimate=4.0*(double)i/(double)n;
        error = fabs(M_PI-pi_estimate)/M_PI;
    }
    return pi_estimate;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    double epsilon = 0.01;
    printf("PI estimate: %lf",monte_carlo(epsilon));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `omp_get_num_threads()` outside a parallel section will always return `1`, as there is only one active thread at the moment the function is called. The following code should give a correct result, but will be much slower than the serial version due to the large parallelization & synchronization overhead spend for doing a very simple operation.

```
#pragma omp parallel private(x, y) reduction(+:i)//OMP parallel directive
{
    x = drand48();
    y = drand48();
    if((x*x+y*y)<=1.0){i+=1;}
    #pragma omp master
    n+=omp_get_num_threads();
}
```

The following avoids repeatedly spawning threads and may be more efficient, but still probably slower.

```
#pragma omp parallel private(x, y)
while(error>=epsilon){
        x = drand48();
        y = drand48();
        if((x*x+y*y)<=1.0){
            #pragma omp atomic
            i++;
        }
    #pragma omp barrier
    #pragma omp single
    {
        n+=omp_get_num_threads();
        pi_estimate=4.0*(double)i/(double)n;
        error = fabs(M_PI-pi_estimate)/M_PI;
        printf("%lf\n", error);
    } // implicit barrier here
}
```

In order to really go faster, a minimum number of iterations should be given such as:

```
#define ITER 1000
#pragma omp parallel private(x, y)
while(error>=epsilon){
    #pragma omp for reduction(+:i)
    for (int j=1;j<ITER;j++){
        x = drand48();
        y = drand48();
        if((x*x+y*y)<=1.0) i+=1;
    }
    /* implicit barrier + implicit atomic addition
     * of thread-private accumulator to shared variable i
     */

    #pragma omp single
    {
        n+=ITER;
        pi_estimate=4.0*(double)i/(double)n;
        error = fabs(M_PI-pi_estimate)/M_PI;
        printf("%lf\n", error);
    } // implicit barrier
}
```

Comment: Can you comment on why you never used shared(i) expansion in parallel block? An object is supposed be declared shared if it will accessed by multiple threads, isn't that right?

Comment: *shared* is the default data-sharing behavior for variables if no attribute is not specified. The default behavior can be turned off with `default(none)`, in which case all variables must be "declared" with a data sharing attribute (*shared*, *private*, *firstprivate*,*lastprivate*,*reduction*...). This is sometime recommended as it helps with debugging (variables must be explicitly "declared" after the `omp parallel` directive, and if any is forgotten this will generate a compilation error rather than runtime issues d/t wrong data-sharing behavior)

Comment: Thank you! That is very explanatory. Could you upvote my question if possible?